# In The Tale of Mr Tod what is Dog Darnel?

Tags: the-tale-of-mr-tod, beatrix-potter

In The Tale of Mr Tod, Beatrix Potter mentions a substance to be found in a hole:

> There he had dug quite a deep hole for dog darnel; and had set a mole trap

What is this substance?

Comment: It may be symbolic of corrupt manners https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=W6INAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA124&ots=-_0VqHQOWY&dq=what%20is%20Dog%20Darnel%3F&pg=PA124#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20Dog%20Darnel?&f=false

Answer (score 5):

The website below defines darnel as a type of weedy grass, and includes the Beatrix Potter quote as an example of its usage. I'm guessing that dog darnel is a local dialect version of the name, or perhaps a variation which has fallen into disuse. It is also known as bearded darnel, and can be mistaken for wheat, with serious consequences, as it is poisonous.

See ["Darnel" at Open Dictionary of English by LearnThat Foundation](https://www.learnthat.org/dictionary/47346_darnel.html).

Comment: per the OED, 'Dog' *In the names of plants, often denoting kinds considered inferior, worthless, or unfit for human consumption*.hence there are lots of plants which are 'dog-something' eg dogwood,dog violet,dog rose,dog daisy. It may be worth noting that the *only* online search results for 'dog darnel' are for The Tale of Mr Tod, so it may be a usage which was always highly regional or even restricted to the Potter family.

Comment: I like this answer but won't accept it as it does not explain why a badger would dig a deep whole to get it.